# MySQL - find optimal index for query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization

I have query: `SELECT DISTINCT a1, a2, a3 FROM t WHERE a4 = '' ORDER BY a1, a5`

and index: `(a4, a1, a5, a2, a3)`

Query explain: `Using where; Using index; Using temporary`

What fields order in the index is optimal or perhaps query can be optimized?

**UPD**

`EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`:

```json
    {
     "query_block": {
       "select_id": 1,
       "temporary_table": {
         "function": "buffer",
         "table": {
           "table_name": "t",
           "access_type": "range",
           "possible_keys": ["my_index"],
           "key": "my_index",
           "key_length": "92",
           "used_key_parts": ["a4"],
           "rows": 113479,
           "filtered": 100,
           "attached_condition": "(t.a4 = '')",
           "using_index": true
         }
       }
     }
```

Comment: Without the `DISTINCT`, I think your index is the best.  Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Comment: @RickJames I added information to the question

Comment: How many rows do you get without `DISTINCT`?  (`SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE a4='';`)

Comment: @RickJames about 120 000

Comment: Sounds as if the `DISTINCT` in not needed?

Comment: @RickJames I don't think so, the difference with and without distinct is almost 10 times (±12 000 vs 120 000 results)

Answer (score 0):

For your query, it would seem that the optimal index would be:

```
(a4, a1, a2, a3, a5)
-^ for the where clause
-----^ returned in the select and perhaps used for the select distinct
-----------------^ covers the query so the data pages are not fetched
```

That said, your query will still need to sort the results.  I don't think there is a way to eliminate that using the index.

Comment: I added your index, but mysql picks from the two mine. Query explain with your index: `Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort`

Comment: @Vv.  . . . In that case, MySQL does not know how to use the index for the aggregation and so the two are equivalent.  Other databases have smarter optimizers.

Comment: @Vv. - Did you _time_ it with that index?  Ans what does `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` say for it?

Answer (score 0):

The index you have is the best you're going to get for that query.

The `DISTINCT` query modifier is forcing the query to use a temp table to accumulate the distinct rows so far.

But at least your query doesn't have to read the table. It gets all the columns it needs from reading the index alone. That's the `Using index` note you see in the EXPLAIN. This advantage is called a "covering index."

You do not see `Using filesort` when it uses your index, because the optimizer relies on reading the index in the order of `(a1, a5)` which is what you wanted (given all the rows are otherwise tied on a single value of `(a4)`. So it doesn't need to do any extra sorting of the result.